# How should this algebraic fraction be solved.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\frac{2x}{3x-4}-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{2}{3}$

How should this fraction be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac { 2x }{ 3x-4 } -\frac { 1 }{ x } =\frac { 2 }{ 3 } \\ \frac { 2{ x }^{ 2 }-3x+4 }{ x\left( 3x-4 \right)  } =\frac { 2 }{ 3\\  } \\ 6{ x }^{ 2 }-9x+12=6{ x }^{ 2 }-8x\\ x=12$$

Answer (score 2):

The given equation is equivalent to
$$0=\frac{2x}{3x-4}-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2}{3}=\frac{2x\cdot 3\cdot x-3\cdot(3x-4)-2\cdot x\cdot(3x-4)}{3x(3x-4)}\\
=\frac{6x^2-(9x-12)-(6x^2-8x)}{3x(3x-4)}=\frac{12-x}{3x(3x-4)}.$$
Once we state that $x\not=0$ and $x\not=4/3$, then  it suffices to discuss the equation given by the numerator equal to zero. Hence we conclude that there is only one solution: $x=12$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Multiply by a common denominator so as to clear all fractions.

Comment: the condition $ x \neq 0 \text{ and} x \neq \frac{4}{3}$ shall be added

Comment: @G Cab. Agreed.  This was a hint.  The solution one comes up with from the hint does not produce either of the forbidden values.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{2x}{3x-4}-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{2}{3}$$
multiply by $3x(3x-4) \quad{x\neq0 \text{ and} x\neq \frac{4}{3}}$
$$6x^2-3(3x-4)=2x(3x-4)$$

Answer (score 1):

first of all we have $$x\ne 4/3,x\ne 0$$ and we can multiply by $$3\cdot x\cdot (3x-4)$$ and we obtain
$$2x\cdot 3x-3(3x-4)=2x(3x-4)$$ can you proceed?